# Return value from callback function in service to component

Tags: javascript, angular, callback, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I'm using the Cordova  [WifiWizard Plugin](https://github.com/hoerresb/WifiWizard) in my Ionic 2 mobile app. Everything works fine, when I run it in the *.ts file of my page. In this case my code looks like:

**Declaring WifiWizard** before @Component:

```
declare var WifiWizard:any;
```

**Call of WifiWizard and success / error methods:**

```
setCurrentWifiAsHomeWifi() {
  WifiWizard.getCurrentSSID(this.ssidSuccess, this.ssidError);    
}

ssidSuccess = (ssid) => {
   this.userService.setHomeWifi(this.user.$key, ssid);
};

ssidError = (err) => {
  console.log("WiFi Wizard Error"+err);
};
```

However, I don't want to put all this wifi-logic in the page-component, but move it to a wifi provider / service instead. But I don't get this service to return the ssid-string to the component.

---

***EDIT:***

I tried many different things and I carefully read the post, linked by gyre (thank you for that). However, I still can't figure out a solution for my problem, and I think it's slightly different to the linked question.

Let me sketch the structure of my problem to make it more obviously to you:
[image: structure of my serviceCall]

I'm calling the wifiService from homePage.ts, e.g. using a promise:

```
setCurrentWifiAsHomeWifi() {
  this.wifiService.loadWifiData().then( result=> {
  console.log("returned SSID: "+result);
});
```

In wifiService.ts I need to implement "loadWifiData" which calls the wifiWizard plugin like this:

```
WifiWizard.getCurrentSSID(this.getWifiSuccess, this.getWifiError);
```

If this is successful, it passes the SSID-string to the "getWifiSuccess" method, if it fails it passes the error to "getWifiError". However the plugin call doesn't return any value to my homePage.

How can I return the outcome (SSID or error) to my homePage? I'm stuck here. Appreciate your help! Hope it became clearer now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @gyre yeah I think it is a duplicate.

Comment: @gyre: thank you for the link. I carefully read through all the answers but I still can't get it running. I think my problem is slightly different than in the suggested question. I edited my question to make it clearer. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by letting loadWifiData() return a Promise and defining the code for the success- and reject-function directly in this Promise.

```
 loadWifiData() {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
      WifiWizard.getCurrentSSID(
        // if successful:
        (ssid => {
          resolve (ssid);
        })
        , 
        // if error:
        (error => { 
          reject (error); 
        })
      )
    });    
  }
```